# Immutable js - best way to extract values from a deeply nested object in a declarative way?

Tags: functional-programming, immutable.js

Let say I get a json back from an API call with this shape once parsed:

```
const foos = {
  foo1: {
    bar1: [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}],
   bar2: [{a:4},{a:5},{a:6}],
    bar3: [{a:7},{a:8},{a:9}]
  },
  foo2: {
    bar4: [{a:10},{a:11},{a:12}],
    bar5: [{a:13},{a:14},{a:15}]
  }
}
```

Then, I wrap it in `fromJs()` to make it immutable.

Next, I need to iterate over that object to extract values this way and do whatever I want with it:

```
var obj = {aValue: 0}

Object.keys(foos).forEach( key => {    
  Object.keys(foos[key]).forEach( nestedKey => {
    foos[key][nestedKey].forEach(el => {
      obj.aValue = el.a
      console.log(obj)
    })    
  })
})
```

in the console:

```
{ aValue: 1 }
{ aValue: 2 }
{ aValue: 3 }
{ aValue: 4 }
{ aValue: 5 }
{ aValue: 6 }
{ aValue: 7 }
{ aValue: 8 }
{ aValue: 9 }
{ aValue: 10 }
{ aValue: 11 }
{ aValue: 12 }
{ aValue: 13 }
{ aValue: 14 }
{ aValue: 15 }
```

What would be the best way to do this with Immutable JS in a declarative way?

Comment: Mutating an object and logging it to the console repeatedly is not exactly functional, or would benefit from doing it declaratively. What is your actual problem, what result data structure do you need?

Comment: I need to extract all these values, console.log is just for the example. I'll go too domain specific if I tell you what I do with the value, so I don't think it matters. The code is far from being functional but I'd like to slowly migrate it this way. My concern was just more to learn how to use Immutable JS correctly

Comment: But extract into what? An iterator? An array? Some immutable.js structure?

Comment: I'd populate another object with this value, if that makes sense, as in the console.log, expect another values are already present {prop1:..., prop2:..., aValue: 1 } ... for example with Immutable, I could probably use a Record with default values and insert this one in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`flatten`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/flatten), which creates a new, flattened Collection.

```
// flatten the first two levels
const foos =  Immutable.fromJS({...});
const flatCollection = foos.flatten(2);
flatCollection.forEach(val => console.log('flat entry', val.get('a')));
```

If you only want to crawl through the data instead of creating a collection, crawling through the layers with Immutable's `forEach` might be the better (and faster) approach. This could also be combined with `.reduce`

```js
const foos = Immutable.fromJS({
  foo1: {
    bar1: [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}],
    bar2: [{a:4},{a:5},{a:6}],
    bar3: [{a:7},{a:8},{a:9}]
  },
  foo2: {
    bar4: [{a:10},{a:11},{a:12}],
    bar5: [{a:13},{a:14},{a:15}]
  }
});

// go into all immmutable collections and process their values
function deepLoop(value, key) {
  if (Immutable.isCollection(value)) {
    value.forEach(deepLoop);
  } else {
    console.log('primitive entry', key, value);
  }
}
foos.forEach(deepLoop);

// go into all maps and process the lists differently
function deepMap(value, key, context) {
  if (Immutable.Map.isMap(value)) {
    value.forEach(deepMap, key);
  } else {
    value.forEach(val => console.log('list entry', val.get('a')));
  }
}
foos.forEach(deepMap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.12/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, the solution with forEach works. The first one with flatten actually just keep the last value of 'a' in the array if I am not mistaken.

Comment: flatten doesn't work so well because it merges all attributes with the same name, unless you select an upper level, e.g. `.flatten(2);` where you end up with the full object